# Determining the Active Window name or id

Tags: windows, vb.net

hello im using `VB 2008`

is it possible to get active window name or id?

for example i have active notepad window, now how i can get it's process name or process ?id(better is process id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Pinvoke to execute some Win32 API to get all this info.
Below is the sequence of Pinvoke that you need to use.

- GetForegroundWindow (to get current active window handle - hwnd)
- GetWindowThreadProcessId (to get the process ID and thread ID for the hwnd that you got in the above API call)

Comment: i got this error : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: How are you using the second Pinvoke ? as this is the API which requires you to pass a pointer to it. Refer http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowthreadprocessid for using this from pinvoke